# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module Vue.js single component file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm creating my `.vue` components files to remove the templates from the `index.html` file of my SPA. 
After I've moved the first component to a separate file, I get this error in console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. I'm not using webpack, browserify babel or similar tools, I'm just using javascript. How I can fix this problem and import single file components inside the main javascript file of the app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use regular JavaScript files, `.vue` files are supported only via `vue-cli`, since they are compiled. This solution works, allowing you to split your logic over multiple files, just like you do with `.vue` templates.

**index.html**

```
<head>
   <!-- TODO: your imports here... -->

   <script src="path/to/MyComponent.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="app">
      <my-component></my-component>
   </div>

   <script>
   new Vue({
      el: '#app'
   });
   </script>
</body>
```

**MyComponent.js**

```
const MyComponent = Vue.component('my-component', {
   data () {
      // Your data here...
   },
   methods: {
      // Your methods here...
   },
   template: '<p>Hello, world!</p>'
});
```

More informations can be found [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html).